# Unable to select value from dropdown python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to pass/ select city name/station in Wunderground website, but unable select the city name from the dropdown list. From the below picture how to select "New York City,NY". Here is my code

[image]

CODE:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.wunderground.com/")
time.sleep(10)
driver.maximize_window()

Search_city = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="wuSearch"]')
Search_city.send_keys('new york')
Search_city = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="wuForm"]/search-autocomplete/ul/li[2]').click()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle dynamic element use WebDriverWait() and wait for elemement to be clickable.

Code:

```
driver.get("https://www.wunderground.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="wuSearch"]'))).send_keys("new york")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'New York City')]"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. Cant we select the first element without passing "New York City"?

Comment: Yes you can, just replace the last line with this. `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="wuForm"]/search-autocomplete/ul/li[2]/a'))).click()`